# Item (Magento\Review\Model\Review\Interceptor) with the same ID "4" already exists

Tags: magento-2.1, php-7, product-review

I am using Magento 2.1.7 version.
The customer is able to write a review from product detail page, and review is approved by admin.
But Customer reviews is not showing in product detail page.
This block is showing empty
`<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>`
and getting this error in console

> http://xxx/review/product/listAjax/id/200/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I hit this Link in the browser then getting this error -
Item (`Magento\Review\Model\Review\Interceptor`) with the same ID "4" already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your collection is loading multiple items which has more than 1 row with `ID` `4`.

So use add `group by` **clause** to your collection primary key. 
For eg: `$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.review_id');`

So this will skip loading duplicate entries.

Collection may have been loading same entries because of wrong join or joined table may have same column name with same value is being loaded. So please check you query try printing it and execute in phpmyadmin check if same ID exits. And you may need to add group by as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But there is no duplicate entries

Comment: No no, not duplicate entries. Collection may have been loading same entries because of wrong join or joined table may have same column name with same value is being loaded. So please check you query. And you may need to add group by as well

Comment: Actually we are using magento core functionality so why this problem is comming

Comment: is any one there who face same problem ?